# terraform Route53_record keeps getting destroyed and recreated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-route53

I was tryingto host a statis site on S3 as a website. I got it working fine and I can the site using the website endpoint on the bucket. after that, I tried to use a custom domain to access it by creating a Route53 alias record using the below terraform script:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "site" {
  bucket = "${var.ui_bucket_name}.${var.root_domain}"
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }

  error_document {
    key = "index.html"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id

  acl = "public-read"
  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.site,
    aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.site
  ]
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "PublicReadGetObject"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = "*"
        Action    = "s3:GetObject"
        Resource = [
          aws_s3_bucket.site.arn,
          "${aws_s3_bucket.site.arn}/*",
        ]
      },
    ]
  })

  depends_on = [
    aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.site
  ]
}


module "template_files" {
  source = "hashicorp/dir/template"

  base_dir = "${path.module}/../../../client_ui/build"

}
resource "aws_s3_object" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.site.bucket
  for_each = module.template_files.files
  key          = each.key
  content_type = each.value.content_type

  # The template_files module guarantees that only one of these two attributes
  # will be set for each file, depending on whether it is an in-memory template
  # rendering result or a static file on disk.
  source  = each.value.source_path
  content = each.value.content

  # Unless the bucket has encryption enabled, the ETag of each object is an
  # MD5 hash of that object.
  etag = each.value.digests.md5
}




data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  name         = var.root_domain
  private_zone = false
}


resource "aws_route53_record" "www-a" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name = aws_s3_bucket.site.bucket
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration.site.website_domain
    zone_id                = aws_s3_bucket.site.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

later on, when I was working on a different service in AWS, I updated a different part of the terraform script not related to this S3 bucket and route53 then I applied the terraform script, I noticed that the route53 record was destroyed and recreated.

I reviewed the changes and made sure that I did not changed anything that should destroy and recreate the route53 record.

just to be sure, I invoked the terraform apply command multiple times without changing anything at all (terraform or any other file). still, the route53 record is getting destroyed and recreated.

edit:
not sure what happened, today when I applied the terraform plan. it worked fine without recreating the record.
not sure if this is related or not, but it might be because I was applying the plan partially before.

Comment: It would be good to see the `terraform plan` output related to the Route 53 record, to see what it thinks has changed that requires the record to be recreated. There should be some indication in the plan output.